# Adding bytes to a String when porting from Python2 to Python3 to write to a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, encryption

As my first Python project, I am trying to port a decryption tool from Python2 to Python3, which decrypts a series of files.

The original Python2 code is as follows:

```
decrypted = ''

for i in xrange(len(content)):
    keybytenum = i & 0xF
    xorbytenum = i & 0x1FF
    contentbyte = ord(key[keybytenum:keybytenum + 1]) ^ ord(xortable[xorbytenum:xorbytenum + 1]) ^ ord(content[i:i + 1])
    decrypted += chr(contentbyte)

fd = open(base + 'decrypted' + os.path.sep + 'CONTENT.DAT', 'wb')
fd.write(decrypted)
fd.close()
```

After changing the `xrange` to `range` I got the following error when writing to the file (`fd.write(decrypted`):
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

I then tried changing
`decrypted = ''` to `decrypted = b''` but then received an error in `decrypted += chr(contentbyte)` saying `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`

There was no way I could find to change the value of `contentbyte` to bytes so that I could append it to `decrypted` so later on I tried changing `decrypted` back to string and writing to the file by encoding the value of `decrypted` like this `fd.write(decrypted.encode('ascii', errors='replace'))`. This allows the program to run but the output is not the same as with Python2, this gets me strings wrapped with `b''`.

If I do a `.decode('utf-8')` the strings look good but I get a lot of bad output, in a hex editor I get a lot of `3F` values where Python2 will have different values.

I'm not sure what to try anymore. Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try next? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Tried more things but nothing worked:

```
decrypted += contentbyte  # TypeError: can't concat int to bytes

decrypted += contentbyte.to_bytes(1, 'big', signed=False)  # Hangs

decrypted += contentbyte.to_bytes(1, 'little', signed=False)  # Hangs

decrypted += struct.pack("B", contentbyte)  # Hangs

decrypted += six.int2byte(contentbyte)  # Hangs

decrypted += bytes(contentbyte)  # Hangs

decrypted += bytes([contentbyte])  # Hangs
```

Not sure what to try next

**EDIT 2:**

I tried again with one of the methods that I thought was hanging but it turns out it was actually working, only very very slowly! It took about 30 min in python3 but it worked and I got the same output as the python2 code. However, the Python2 version takes about 5 seconds.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can speed this up?

**EDIT 3:**

Finally got this to work fast, here is what worked in the end:

```
decrypted = ''

for i in range(len(content)):
    keybytenum = i & 0xF
    xorbytenum = i & 0x1FF
    contentbyte = ord(key[keybytenum:keybytenum + 1]) ^ ord(xortable[xorbytenum:xorbytenum + 1]) ^ ord(content[i:i + 1])
    decrypted += chr(contentbyte)

fd = open(base + 'decrypted' + os.path.sep + 'CONTENT.DAT', 'wb')
fd.write(bytes(decrypted, encoding="raw_unicode_escape"))
fd.close()
```

This code is a bit ugly because it works with strings and then converts to bytes but at least the conversion is done only once and not in a loop, resulting in the code completing in a few seconds and not in 30 minutes like the previous attempts.

Comment: you were on a good way when you changed `decrypted` to  `b''`, but then you try to append string, which (as you know) wont work. So instead of using `chr(contentbyte)` -which changes it to `str`, append only the `contentbyte`, which as the name suggest should be `bytes` type instead of `str`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did try that, however, what came out of contentbyte was actually ```int``` and not ```byte```, it gave a ```TypeError: can't concat int to bytes```.

I tried a ```decrypted += six.int2byte(contentbyte)``` and a few other ways of converting but then it just hangs,

Comment: I tried some more things to no avail
```# decrypted += contentbyte  # TypeError: can't concat int to bytes```

```# decrypted += contentbyte.to_bytes(1, 'big', signed=False)  # Hangs```

```# decrypted += contentbyte.to_bytes(1, 'little', signed=False)  # Hangs```

```# decrypted += struct.pack("B", contentbyte)  # Hangs```

```# decrypted += six.int2byte(contentbyte)  # Hangs```

```# decrypted += bytes(contentbyte)  # Hangs```

```decrypted += bytes([contentbyte])  # Hangs```

Not sure what to try next

Comment: I was mislead by the variable name. try this: `decrypted += chr(contentbyte).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Hi @yedpodtrzitko I think that works as well, kind of like the methods I posted. They work but it takes a really long time to finish. It seems that converting to bytes on a loop is expensive. After trying many more things I finally got it to work fast by changing the ```decrypted``` var back to string and this line:

```fd.write(bytes(decrypted, encoding="raw_unicode_escape"))```

It is ugly because I left the variable as string and not as bytes, I'll edit my original post with the final code.

It does seem kind of ugly, so if you have a suggestion I'd be happy to take it!